# Pixelated java GUI in Windows 7 after migrating to AdoptOpenJDK 11

Tags: windows-7, java-11, blurry, highdpi

I'm migrating a java application from java 8 (Oracle) to java 11 (AdaptOpenJDK).
The version that was using java 8 used to have layout problems on windows 10 with high dpi displays.
Once I built using java 11 the problem went away, and GUI looks fine in Windows 10.
However, I found that the new build with java 11 does not look ok on Windows 7, GUI images and text appear pixelated.

Summary:

- GUI with java 8 is fine on Win 7 but does not look ok in Win 10
- GUI with java 11 is fine on Win 10 but does not look ok in Win 7

I'm using a 4k monitor at 3840x2160 with 125% scaling.

I found that if I use the java 8 JRE (from AdoptOpenJDK) to run the application, then the problem in Windows 7 goes away. It seems the problem is caused by java 11 doing a 125% scaling since I found the GUI is approximately 25% larger.

I'd like to find a solution in Windows 7 when using java 11. I wonder whether there is any javaw argument I can use or any system setting I can change.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

**Update**

Screenshots of all combinations on java version and windows are attached.

- **[java8 win 7.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ly7Q.jpg) :** looks ok (no scaling), only drawback text and images small regardless of scaling configuration on system
- **[java8 win 10.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hkKm.png) :** scaling is not applied to icons - cluttered JTree
- **[java11 win 10.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ljol.png) :** looks ok - proper scaling
- **[java11 win 7.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y51o6.jpg) :** scaling applied but it shows problems - icons and text appear pixelated

**Solution**

This is not actually a solution, but I want to share what I believe it's happening after some research.

This [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows?redirectedfrom=MSDN) describes the DPI awareness modes and which ones are in each Windows version. The behavior for all Windows versions previous to 8.1 will always apply Bitmap-stretching which causes the blurry UIs. 
Stretching does not occur in Java 8 because it's not dpi-aware but it has a more serious problem on high scaling percentages (cluttering, huge text and small images/icons). Stretching occurs in java 11, since it's dpi-aware, however it has the blurriness problem due to the stretching behavior implemented in Windows 7.

Comment: Can you attach some screenshots?

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Sorry for the delay. I included the images. Thanks

Comment: Is this a Swing or SWT UI?